# Unexpected reply from Skype

Tags: skype4py

skype4py raises an exception running the following code:

```
def createChat():
   chat = skype.CreateChatWith('another.user')
   chat.SendMessage('Gonna add new.user.')
   chat.AddMembers(skype.User('new.user'))
```

the error is:

```
SkypeError: [Errno 0] Unexpected reply from Skype, got [ALTER CHAT ADDMEMBERS], expected [ALTER CHAT #some.user/$another.user;newuserid ADDMEMBERS (...)]
```

This makes me think there might be a bug in _DoCommand() in Skype4Py/skype.py

The code in that function checks that the skype api returns the command string and it appears that the command string is returned without the parameters sent. Certainly startswith() will not work for testing the return string in this instance.

Is skype4py still maintained? Is this a bug or amidoinitwrong?

Comment: Skype4Py is maintained here https://github.com/awahlig/skype4py Please submit a bug report, a way to repeat the issue (test.py file) and possible patch if known. Thanks!